# How to join join two classes and print report based on a third "bridge entity" [java]

Tags: java, collections

I have some .txt files, which I read in to build two objects.

Item, with fields:

```
Description|SKU|Retail Price|Discount
```

and Store with fields:

```
ID|Description|Street|City|Province|Postal Code|Store Phone|Auto Service
```

I have another .txt file for the Inventory object, which is a bridge entity which ties them together. Inventory's fields are:

```
Store ID|Item SKU|Item Count
```

Obviously, those come from the Item and Store classes.

Here is my objective:

**I want to create an inventory report which synthesizes the three lists into a single console printed output, but am hitting a wall about how to get there.**

This is about as far as I got:

```
public static void write(List<Item> items, List<Store> stores, List<Stock> stocks) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Inventory Report");
    System.out.println("----------------");


    for (Item it : items) {
        for (Stock s : stocks) {
            if(it.getProductNumber() == s.getItemSKU()) {
                for (Store st: stores) {
                    if(st.getId() == s.getStoreID()) {
                        System.out.println(it.getDescription() + "is from store" + st.getId() + "in" + st.getCity()  + "and costs" + it.getPrice());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the obvious solution should be creating tables and putting the info in, but this is an assignment that says that I should do it using pure java...

I am probably close, but my logic is off here... How best could one cross reference two Classes based on the third class?

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your Items and Stores in Maps, where their Id is the key:

```
    Map<Integer, Item> items = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
    Map<Integer, Store> stores = new HashMap<Integer, Store>();
```

Pass them to your output method and it is easy as cake:

**EDIT**:*Had little errors in the lines with a comment, fixed it.*

```
public static void write(Map<Integer, Item> items, Map<Integer, Store> stores, List<Stock> stocks) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Inventory Report");
    System.out.println("----------------");

    for(Stock stock : stocks) { // <-- for all Stocks
        Store store = stores.get(stock.getStoreID()); // <-- get Store
        Item item = items.get(stock.getItemSKU());  // <-- get Item
        System.out.println(item.getDescription() + "is from store" + store.getId() + "in" + store.getCity()  + "and costs" + item.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm reading the .txt files in... Do I create the hashmap as I read each Item in? How would I do that?

Comment: Create the `HashMap` once before you start reading, and then fill it. After you create your `Item item` call `items.put(item.getID(), item);`, so instead of putting the item into your list like you did before, put it in the map.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do below:

Create tow Maps as:

```
    Map<String, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<String, Item>();
    Map<String, Store> storeMap = new HashMap<String, Store>();
```

While reading the `items`, populate the `itemMap` using `SKU` as key and `Item` object as value. Similarly, while reading `stores`, populate `storeMap` with `id` as key and `Store` object as value.

Now when you read the second file, retrieve the corresponding `Item` and `Store` objects from `itemMap` and `storeMap` respectively using the `SKU` and `ID` and use the attributes as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing sequential search, consider using a map.

```
for (Item it : items) {
    Stock stock = stockMap.get(it.getProductNumber());
    Store store = storeMap.get(stock.getStoreId());

    System.out.println(".....");
}
```

Comment: Many stores could sell the same product, so what would `stockMap.get(it.getProductNumber());` return?

Comment: this is just an example.  Change to whatever fits your needs. For example, instead of having `Map<ProductNumber, Stock>`, use `Map<ProductNumber, List<Stock>>` instead.

Comment: or go the easy way, as i did in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Item.SKU` is a unique key.

You can perform a many-to-one join by iterating the entries on the many-side and selecting the corresponding entries on the one-side. Here, you have a table you can iterate over, the bridge:

```
- build an index for the first table:
 - for every row, insert it to a map ID => row. You can use a HashMap
- build an index for the second table

- for every row in the bridge table
 - select the appropriate row in the first table using your index
 - select the appropriate row in the second table
 - print/store the data
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the *point here is, but I think the easiest thing to do is to create a merged object that would contain the values from all three and load the values of each of your lists into individual items of this merged object. What you join them on is arbitrary, obviously. This, as you said, is a job best suited for a database, but if you must have it in pure java, I think a single object that holds all the values is the way to go.

Comment: The question is _how_ to perform the join.

Comment: Indeed. I'm having trouble with my for loops here. I was hoping someone could help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure given your sample code what exactly you want to be joining on, but whatever it is, you create a class that contains all these values and then you do a loop through your various lists looking for that particular field value to match, and then pull all the other values into the given instance of that object.

Comment: I see. That is easy if there are only 2 things to cross reference, but I guess my 10th grade mind is having trouble wrapping my head around doing it with three. Could you possibly walk me through how to do it with joining two elements based on a third element?

Comment: you don't need to do it all at once... do it one thing at a time. First loop through the first object and just pack it with the SKU, then loop through the second object looking for the same SKU, RetailPrice, Discount, and Description.  Then loop through that list comparing it to the second file and pack it with the second set of fields, then lastly loop through the third file looking for matching IDs and pack those fields in. Now you have a list of merged objects which you can print out.